# LINQ query throws an InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I was roaming around in different sites for casting techniques and I constructed the following code to cast to from `float` to `int` as shown below

```
var floatList = new float[] { 2.7f, 3.1f, 4.5f };
var intList = from int test1 in floatList 
              select test1;

foreach (var v in intList) 
    Console.Write("{0} ", v.ToString());
```

But above code throws an `InvalidCastException`. Why is this? I thought it is supposed to print `3,3` and `4`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A LINQ clause of the form:

```
from X x in y
```

is equivalent to

```
y.Cast<X>()
```

and then using `x` as the range variable later. The rest of your query is degenerate, so your code is equivalent to:

```
var intList = floatList.Cast<int>();
```

Now [`Enumerable.Cast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does *not* do conversions like this - it *just* does reference conversions and boxing/unboxing conversions. For any other conversions, you need `Select`:

```
var intList = floatList.Select(x => (int) x);
```

Or if you really to use a query expression:

```
var intList = from x in floatList select (int) x;
```

... but personally for simple queries like this, I *wouldn't* use a query expression - I'd just use the method call as shown above.

Comment: +1 for being very insightful on what actually happens.

Comment: thanx for answering Jon and yes I would love to go for simple query ..and what should be the answer here :- 2,3,4 or 3,3,4?

Comment: @Neel, I think you want to round, rather than cast right? In that case, you can use `var intList = floatList.Select(x => (int)Math.Round(x));`

Comment: @Neel: "should" is a matter of your required behaviour, and we can't possibly know that. In some cases you just want to cast, in other cases you want to round. What do these values represent? What are you going to do with them later?

Comment: ok thanx @JonSkeet I am not going to use any of them later it was just for learning purpose :)

Answer (score 5):

This is because there are not `int`s in `floats` and by `int i` you're specifying to look for `int`s, causing an internal cast that doesn't work (like `int i = 2.7f;`).

I think this would be the way it works:

```
var ints = from f in floats 
           select (int)f;
```